# Em Python existe alguma função pra debug equivalente ao "print_r" ou "var_dump" do PHP?

Tags: python, debug

Em Python existe alguma função pra debug equivalente ao `print_r` ou `var_dump` do PHP?

Por exemplo, em PHP:

```
$valor = 'Hello';

var_dump($valor); string(5)'Hello'
```

Em Python teria alguma função similar para debug?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesta [biblioteca](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) para debug.

Answer (score 3):

***[repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html)*** (Python 2) e ***[reprlib](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/reprlib.html)*** (Python 3)

> Produz uma representação em forma de string de um objeto passado como
>   parâmetro.

[***pprint()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

> Produz saída formatada para os dados.

***[Exemplo](https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/)*** (fonte: **pymotw.com**):

```
from pprint import pprint

from pprint_data import data

print 'PRINT:'
print data
print
print 'PPRINT:'
pprint(data)
$ python pprint_pprint.py

PRINT:
[(0, {'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B', 'e': 'E', 'd': 'D', 'g': 'G', 'f': 'F', 'h': 'H'}), (1, {'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B', 'e': 'E', 'd': 'D', 'g': 'G', 'f': 'F', 'h': 'H'}), (2, {'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B', 'e': 'E', 'd': 'D', 'g': 'G', 'f': 'F', 'h': 'H'})]

PPRINT:
[(0,
  {'a': 'A',
   'b': 'B',
   'c': 'C',
   'd': 'D',
   'e': 'E',
   'f': 'F',
   'g': 'G',
   'h': 'H'}),
 (1,
  {'a': 'A',
   'b': 'B',
   'c': 'C',
   'd': 'D',
   'e': 'E',
   'f': 'F',
   'g': 'G',
   'h': 'H'}),
 (2,
  {'a': 'A',
   'b': 'B',
   'c': 'C',
   'd': 'D',
   'e': 'E',
   'f': 'F',
   'g': 'G',
   'h': 'H'})]
```

Essas funções do PHP são funções de *output/writing on screen*, sendo que [**var_dump**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php) tem a peculiaridade de mostrar informações sobre a variável.

Para ter uma boa aproximação da função ***var_dump***, você pode usar assim em *Python* 2.7.* e *Python* 3:

```
print(vars(a))
```

Como observado pelo @Miguel, [vars()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) só funciona se o "a" tiver atributo **dict**, que é um dicionário ou mapeamento de um objeto que armazena atributos desse objeto, se for inteiro ou string, *e.g.*, já não dá.

Você pode usar o [***debugger* do Python (PDB)**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

```
#!python3

'''
    Exemplo de uso do debugger do Python
'''
#Importa a biblioteca PDB
import pdb
#Inicie seu programa
objeto = "maçã"

#Ponto onde o debugger vai começar a exibir informação sobre o programa
pdb.set_trace()
sujeito = "Mauricio"
verbo = "gosta"

frase = sujeito + " " + verbo + " " + objeto

print(frase)
```

Comment: Eu acho que isso só funciona se o `a` tiver atributo `__dict__`, se for inteiro ou string por ex já não dá

Comment: Tentei aqui e deu esse erro: `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

Comment: Há algumas coisas que podias explicar melhor, e deve haver maneiras de fazer +- o pedido, olha aqui: https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=var%20dump%20python . Podes contar com o meu +1 se a resposta for extendida e melhorada

Comment: Eu vou fazer isso sim. Ainda tem outras funções que eu quero colocar aí. Só que eu tô no trabalho agora rsrss.